# Mouse hover to change image style in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a website which is built by wordpress.

In portfolio list, the client wants all thumbnails black&white, and when mouse hover on one thumbnail, the image becomes color.

html code as follows

```
<article class="wgl-portfolio-list_item item wgl_col-1-5 residential animate" style="padding-right: 17.5px; padding-left: 17.5px; padding-bottom: 35px; position: absolute; left: 79.9974%; top: 0px;"><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_wrapper inside_image sub_layer_animation"><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_image"><img src="http://axearchitects.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Sevenoaks-Balwyn_Optimised_2-scaled-1170x1170.jpg" alt=""></div><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_description"><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_description-inner"><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_title"><h4 class="title"><a href="http://axearchitects.com.au/projects/sevenoaks-balwyn/">Sevenoaks, Balwyn</a></h4></div><div class="wgl-portfolio-item_meta"><span class="post_cats"><a href="http://axearchitects.com.au/projects-category/residential/" class="portfolio-category">RESIDENTIAL</a></span></div></div></div><a href="http://axearchitects.com.au/projects/sevenoaks-balwyn/" class="portfolio_link single_link"><i class="portfolio_link-icon flaticon-right-arrow"></i></a></div></article>
```

I used this to make all images B&W:

```
.wgl-portfolio-item_image{
filter:grayscale(1);}
```

then I want to do the step of hover then change. I tried these codes one by one

```
.wgl-portfolio-item_image:hover{
filter:grayscale(0)!important;}
```

and

```
::selection{
filter:grayscale(0)!important;}
```

and

```
::selection, .wgl-portfolio-item_image{
filter:grayscale(0)!important;}
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
$( ".wgl-portfolio-item_image" ).hover(function(){
  alert("hello");
    $(this).css("filter", "grayscale(0)!important");
    
});
```

});

(alert is just for testing if JQuery is really picking up the right class and is working)

but all of them don't feel right and of course didn't work.
The thing is those images don't have ids, they just have classes like above. How can I make sure I'm changing the one that the mouse is hovering? and how I can I change image style.

Thank you

The images already have this: mouse hover, and descriptions appear. I also try to add filter change in the same {}. didn't work.
The website was originally built with Wordpress Elementor. not sure if that information helps

Comment: if you want a `:hover` effect, why are you using `::selection`?

Comment: I didn't use ::selection before, but still don't work. let me change my question a little bit

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that all your images have got the *.wgl-portfolio-item_image* class, all you need to do is writing the following lines inside your CSS file (or inside your style tags alternatively):

```
.wgl-portfolio-item_image{
filter:grayscale(1);
}

.wgl-portfolio-item_image:hover{
    filter:grayscale(0)!important;
}
```

By the way, as you are talking about hover, there is no need for `::selection`.

Have a look at the following code as an example:

```css
div.gallery {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.myImage{
    filter:grayscale(1);
}

.myImage:hover{
    filter:grayscale(0)!important;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Image Gallery</h2>
<h4>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h4>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_5terre.jpg">
      <img class="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4poyn.jpg?s=64&g=1" alt="Cinque Terre" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
      <img class="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4poyn.jpg?s=64&g=1" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
      <img class="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4poyn.jpg?s=64&g=1" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="gallery">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img class="myImage" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4poyn.jpg?s=64&g=1" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: actually this is the first code I tried. didn't work

Comment: But I'm trying it right now and it works perfectly.

Comment: I know it should work and shouldn't be a problem. I'm guessing it has something to do with wordpress. that's why I'm here asking...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it has something to do with WordPress" but I just edited my answer and added a code snippet to it which is an example implementation of what you asked. hope it helps you.

Comment: the first code I tried should work. I just don't understand why it doesn't change...

Comment: Could you please include your HTML section of code as well?

Comment: I just checked your code again. Firstly, I have to say that only a few CSS properties can be applied to the ::selection selector which are color, background, cursor, and outline. Secondly, I checked your code with the ``selection``, too and it worked fine. Finally, I want to mention that I think there's no need for the jQuery code at the end and it may cause the issue as it somehow duplicates the ``:hover`` property of CSS and I think there's no need for that unless it is there for test purpose or you really need that alert message.

Comment: I tried JQuery after css hover not working. alert message is just for testing. And if my Jquery is working, there should be an alert, but there's no alert. So I don't know, I believe my code is right. and you've tested it's correct, but there is just no change on the website.

Answer (score 0):

I just got it working.

So there are two layers, I need to activate the first layer as well.
so the right code should be:

```
.inside_image.sub_layer_animation:hover .wgl-portfolio-item_image{
filter:grayscale(0) !important;}
```